# Angular subscribe response

Tags: angular, response, subscribe

Okay, I'm pretty new to Angular, so I have this little problem. So i'm following the Angular guide (https://angular.io/guide/http). So my problem is that my http-response is always undefined. In debug-tools the response is:

```
{"code":0,"status":"error","message":"Invalid JWT - Authentication failed!"}
```

as it should be. But when I console-log response, it always says

```
This should be the response???:  undefined
```

profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { parse } from 'path';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { getLocaleTimeFormat } from '@angular/common';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { Config } from '../config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  tmp: any;
  token: any;
  tmp2: any;
  config: Config;
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.tmp = this.userService.checkToken(this.token)
      .subscribe((data: Config) => this.config = {
        code: data['code'],
        message: data['message']
      });

    console.log("This should be the response???: ", this.config);
  }

}
```

and the user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { httpFactory } from '@angular/http/src/http_module';
import { Config } from './config';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {


  config: Config;
  items: any;
  readonly url = 'http://localhost:82/phpangular/userSystem/src/api/userCtrl.php';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  checkToken(token) {
   return this.http.post<Config>
   (this.url, {'data': 'checkToken', 'token': token});
  }


}
```

and my interface config.ts

```
export interface Config {

    code: string;
    message: string;
}
```

If someone would give me a pointer, I would be real glad :)

Cheers

- Niko

Comment: Here we go again. You get back an observable of response, and not the response itself, because an HTTP call is **asynchronous**. Once you have called HttpClient and subscribed, you have only **sent** the request. The response will come back much later, and at that point, the callback passed to subscribe will be executed. So, of course the response is undefined right after you're just sent the request. Put your console.log() **inside** the subscribe callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HttpClient data undefined out of subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284763/angular-httpclient-data-undefined-out-of-subscribe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `console.log` should be inside `subscribe` callback

```
this.tmp = this.userService.checkToken(this.token).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.config = <Config>(data);
    console.log("This should be the response???: ", this.config);
  },
  err => {

  });
```

Comment: Yeah, did that. Tried to alert this.config, but it stays undefined. So my problem is, how in earth I get the response value assigned to this.config? And use it out of subscribe-function

Comment: Maybe, yet still the problem is how can I use that data outside subscribe? Because this.config is still undefined outside. EDIT. Got it working, it shows on view and can be fired with button with a right output :). Thanks!

Comment: You can call it after `ngOnInit()` is done. In any other action, like button click.

Comment: Yeah, now I kinda understand how this goes :). Thanks!