# Sending get request to download file generated on the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I am learning the mean stack and I have a file I generate on the server-side of my application I intend to download this file from my angular front end when a button is clicked.
but when I click the button nothing happens, I check my back end the file is generated successfully and everything works fine.
when I access the 'localhost:port/generate-file' from my browser the file gets generated and downloaded successfully so I am thinking I have some issue on the angular part.

Here is the code I used :

ts

```
  downloadFile(): any {
    return this.http
      .get('http://localhost:4000/generated-file', { responseType: 'blob' })
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Markup

```
  <button class="button" (click)="downloadFile()">
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First check if you're getting the response at the angular end by console.log, if yes then do subscribe to your response properly. I don't see anything after .subscribe(). Read abt how to subscribe the response.

Comment: Hey @VinaySomawat thank you for your response, I console logged `console.log(
      this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/generated-file', {
        responseType: 'blob',
      })` and I got an observable object

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way! Read how to subscribe the response. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230312/angular-subscribe-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your API is working fine (if it is returning the file as blob), you can download it using [file-saver.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/generated-file', {
    responseType: 'blob'
}).subscribe(
    response => {
        saveAs(response, 'filename')
    }
);
```

See this [link](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/308#issuecomment-279739618) for a simple example.